# how i can make delegate protocol using segue in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

IBAction in **firstViewController**

```
-(IBAction)pickValue:(id)sender
{
    dropDownVController *drp = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"drpVC"];
    drp._delegateValue=self;

}
```

code in **secondViewController**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger intVal = indexPath.row+1;
    [self._delegateValue selectedValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)intVal]];

}
```

It is not getting back to `firstviewcontroller` method

```
 -(void)selectedValue:(NSString *)value
 {
   [valTextfld setText:value];
 }
```

Comment: do you dismiss 2nd ViewController somewhere? I believe it should be dismissed after you call delegate method.

Comment: i had tried to dismiss the view but it doesn't worked.

Comment: can you include the code how you present your second viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Your are not presenting this controller dropDownVController *drp. I think you are using segue, you should set delegate in prepareForSegue: method, here is an example in swift convert in objective C

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YOUR STORYBOARD SEGUE IDENTIFIER HERE" {
        if let drp = segue.destinationViewController as? dropDownVController {
           drp._delegateValue = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you should set delegate in prepareForSegue, the way you are setting, you are instantiating controller and setting to it but this controller instance is never presented.

Comment: now i did this but still it is not coming back to firstviewcontroller after selecting the value from secondviewcontroller.

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"drpVC"])
    {
        dropDownVController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
       
        vc._delegateValue=self;
    }
}